# Type error in explicitly typed binding - Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeerror

I've been struggling for like an hour to understand some things in higher order functions and now I am at the point that I cannot move any further because of this error:

```
    hof :: [Integer] -> (Integer -> Integer)
    isIn :: [Integer] -> Integer -> Integer
    isIn [] s = 0
    isIn [] _ = 0
    isIn (h:t) s
        | h == s = 0 {-<-------- error points here here-}
        | otherwise = isIn(t) + 1
    hof s = \n -> isIn s n

      ERROR file:.\Lab2.hs:111 - Type error in explicitly typed binding
      *** Term           : isIn
      *** Type           : [Integer] -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
      *** Does not match : [Integer] -> Integer -> Integer
```

Comment: No need to apologise in your question - there's nothing wrong in asking for help.

Answer (score 6):

You are missing the second argument in the recursive call to `isIn`; it should be

```
 | otherwise = isIn t s + 1
 --                   ^
```

While not an error, you also have a redundant base case; `s` and `_` are both irrefutable patterns, so just `isIn [] _ = 0` is sufficient.

Also not an error, but there is no difference between `hof` and `isIn`, as you can eta-reduce the definition to

```
hof s = isIn s
```

and again to

```
hof = isIn
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, you helped me the most today, you actually had the tolerance to answer to all my noob questions. If i had more rep i would +1 you but now i am so low i can't :P.